# How can I return enum options in GraphQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I have an enum in a schema like this:

```
enum Classification {
  A
  B
  C
  D
}
```

And the following query:

```
type Query {
  listClasification: Clasification
}
```

Ant the resolver on the JS code is the following:

```
const classification = {
  A: 'A',
  B: 'B',
  C: 'C',
  D: 'D'
};

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    listClasification: () => {return classification}
  },
};
```

But when I execute the following query:

```
{
  listClasification 
}
```

I got the following error:

> "message": "Enum "Classification" cannot represent value: { A:
> "A", B: "B", C: "C", D: "D" }",

Then, how can solve this error, and return all classifications in a query?

Thanks

Comment: `listClasification: Classification` in the schema means that you will return **one** of these enum values. Not all at once. If want to return multiple values, the only option GraphQL offers is to use a list.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: This: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

The first problem is in your schema: `listClasification` probably needs to return a list of values. The closest thing in GraphQL is an array. Here is the fixed schema with an array of `Clasification`:

```
type Query {
  listClasification: [Clasification]
}
```

The second problem is in your resolver. You want to receive data like `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']` (an array), so that's what your resolver should return. You are currently returning an object, not an array. If you want to convert between your `classification` object and an array, here is the fixed resolver.

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    listClasification: () => { return Object.keys(classification) }
  },
};
```

Note that it could be simpler if your just defined `classification = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.